# How to limit availability of a function to within its own section

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, ld

I am working with an embedded project with limited and disjoint program memory.

I have a problem where the optimizer sometimes creates jump tables for case statements, it puts in a call for `__switch` and places a table of offsets after the call.

The idea is that a `__switch` calculates an offset into the table, adds that to its address and does a short relative jmp.

The problem is that the case statement calling the `__switch` function could be at 0x600xxxxx while _switch is at 0x80xxxxx, the short relative jmp created cannot get back to 0x600xxxxx.

I can do scripts to detect this and fail the build, we can workaround with if statements rather than a case statement.

What I would like is a way to tell the linker to not use `_switch` if it is far away, ie do not call `code::_switch` from `code2::xx`.

The proprietary compiler is based on gnu gcc 4.7.3.

Any ideas?

Alternate answer might be to produce a copy of a given function (`__switch`) in both sections and a way to make optimizer select the closest.

---

Update

I found the `--fno-jump-tables` option, sounds like a good workaround.
Compiler understands it, but it makes no difference to the generated code. 
I am using LTO so maybe the linker needs to understand it, but ld just quits, seeing it as an unknown option.

Also `-fno-tree-switch-conversion`, changes lots of generated code, but does not remove my problem.

Comment: So... your compiler generates bad code?

Comment: I think so, but understandable, embedded code spanning such a code space must be pretty rare.

Out of code space we have sections crammed into any [data] space we can find.

Comment: Instead of `case 123: far_foo();` --> `near_foo() { far_foo(); } ... case 123: near_foo();`

Comment: Like a manual trampoline...

I think it jumps to the body of the case statement, thus avoiding comparisons to see which case statement to execute, it does not jump to the working code. So it would still fail to get back to the body.